# Unexpectedly crashing of service when activity is stopped in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, android-activity, service, crash

I start a service and create new thread (downloading a large file). When my activity is opened application works properly - download first part, second part, third part etc. It can be seen in the film: https://youtu.be/qVItEjR00UY

But when I close my activities, my app unexpectedly crash (not immediately but after some time): https://youtu.be/-Pe-vNgAy1U

Why? When I run application from Visual Studio I have the same situation (without error message).

My service:

```
[Service]
class DownloadsService : Service
{
    DownloadsBroadcastReceiver receiver;
    Notification.Builder notificationBuilder;
    DownloadsData downloadsData;
    int uniqueNumber = 1000;
    bool isStarted;
    bool pauseTask;

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        RegisterReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("com.xamarin.example.TEST"));
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        string downloadsDataToParse = intent.GetStringExtra("downloadsData");
        if (downloadsDataToParse != null)
            downloadsData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DownloadsData>(downloadsDataToParse);
        pauseTask = intent.GetBooleanExtra("pauseTask", false);
        if (isStarted && !pauseTask)
            Log.Info("DAMIAN", "Usługa została już wcześniej uruchomiona");
        else if (isStarted && pauseTask)
        {
            PauseTask();
            Log.Info("DAMIAN", "Wstrzymano");
            UpdateNotification("Wstrzymano");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.Info("DAMIAN", "Usługa została uruchomiona");
            DispatchNotificationThatServiceIsRunning(downloadsData.Nazwa, "Rozpoczynanie");
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                MakeDownload(downloadsData.Zadania, downloadsData.Nazwa, downloadsData.AccountsList);
            })).Start();
            isStarted = true;
        }
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        Log.Info("DAMIAN", "Usuwanie usługi");
        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationManager.Cancel(uniqueNumber);
        isStarted = false;
        base.OnDestroy();
    }

    private void DispatchNotificationThatServiceIsRunning(string title, string content)
    {
        Intent stopIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(DownloadsBroadcastReceiver));
        stopIntent.PutExtra("action", "actionName");
        PendingIntent stopPi = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 4, stopIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);
        stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MainActivity)));
        stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(intent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
        Notification.Action pauseAction = new Notification.Action.Builder(Resource.Drawable.Pause, "Wstrzymaj", stopPi).Build();
        Notification.Action removeAction = new Notification.Action.Builder(Resource.Drawable.Remove, "Usuń", resultPendingIntent).Build();
        notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
            .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .SetContentTitle(title)
            .SetContentText(content)
            .AddAction(pauseAction)
            .AddAction(removeAction);
        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationManager.Notify(uniqueNumber, notificationBuilder.Build());
    }

    private void UpdateNotification(string content)
    {
        notificationBuilder.SetContentText(content);
        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationManager.Notify(uniqueNumber, notificationBuilder.Build());
    }

    private void MakeDownload()
    {
        //download file
    }

    private void PauseTask()
    {
        //pause downloading
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with Foreground Services. In `OnStartCommand` I call  `StartForeground(uniqueNumber, notification);` and service works even after closing acitivities.

Answer (score 1):

> But when I close my activities, my app unexpectedly crash (not immediately but after some time)

Sounds like that you didn't unbind the service when your activities is closed. Please refer to the [Bound Service Lifecycle](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/part_2_-_bound_services/#Bound_Service_Lifecycle).

Try to unbind the service in the `OnStop()` or `OnDestroy()` method of the activity where you bind the service for example:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    UnbindService(serviceConnection);
    base.OnStop();
}
```

Or

```
protected override void OnDestroy ()
{
        base.OnDestroy ();

        if (isBound) {
                UnbindService (demoServiceConnection);
                isBound = false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Understand, but I want to have running service when my activity is closed.